# Error trying to create a SQL Server 2014 function

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL Server function, and what I am trying to do is concatenate the first name and last name from the `Dimcustomers` table. This is the normal query

```
select concat(firstname, ',', lastname) 
from Dimcustomer
```

but when I am trying to generate a function using this small portion of code, everything goes wrong, the function is showing the last row of that table, I ran a while loop in another query and is showing the same thing.

This is the while loop

```
declare @contador int
set @contador = (Select count(Firstname) from dimcustomer)
declare @fullname nvarchar(50)

while @contador <= (select count(Firstname) from dimcustomer)
begin
    select  @fullname = concat(firstname, ',', lastname) 
    from Dimcustomer

    print @fullname
end
```

This is the function

```
Create Function Names (@Fullname nvarchar(50))
    Returns nvarchar(50)
as
Begin
    Declare @Firstname nvarchar(50)
    Declare @Lastname nvarchar(50)

    select 
        @firstname = Firstname, @Lastname = Lastname, 
        @fullname = concat(@Firstname, ',', @Lastname) 
    from 
        DimCustomer

    return @Fullname
end
```

When I ran the functions this is the result

[image]

It's supposed to must concatenate the first name and the last name, what would be the correct query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Tried this, and it Works for me! thanks everybody.

```
CREATE FUNCTION THISNAME (@GEOGRAPHYKEY INT)

RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @MINAME NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @MINAME=(FIRSTNAME+' '+LASTNAME) FROM DIMCUSTOMER
   WHERE GeographyKey=@GEOGRAPHYKEY
     RETURN @MINAME 
END

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** a function in SQL Server **must always** include the schema its defined in - when created and also when called!

I would suggest **not** accessing the table at all inside your function - instead, just **pass in** first and last name as parameters:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateFullName 
    (@Firstname NVARCHAR(50),
     @Lastname NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONCAT(@Firstname, ',', @Lastname) 
END
```

Then you can call this function something like this:

```
SELECT
    FirstName, LastName,
    dbo.CreateFullName(FirstName, LastName) 
FROM
    DimCustomer
```

If you really need a **function** for this is debatable - you could just as easily just put the `CONCAT` directly into that select......

Functions are notoriously slow - *especially* when you're doing some table access *inside* the function. I prefer to try and avoid that if ever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems some problem in you function, there is no `where` clause in your function to select individual name from the table

```
Create Function Names (@Id int )
    Returns nvarchar(50)
as
Begin
    select  
        @fullname = concat(isnull(Firstname,''), ',', isnull(Lastname,'')) 
    from 
        DimCustomer where id = @id

    return @Fullname
end

Go
```

You may call this function in your table as

```
 select id, firstname, lastname, dbo.Names(id) from DimCustomer
```

Moreover, if you already have `firstname`, `lastname` then you can directly apply concatenate in your query

```
 select firstname, lastname, 
 concat(isnull(firstname,'') , ',' , isnull(lastname,'')) 
 from DimCustomer
```